# ethereumにてgethをバックグラウンドで動かしたい

Tags: ethereum

ubuntu(wsl)上でethereumをいじっているのですが、gethをバックグラウンドで動かせません。
最初に下記のコマンドを入力しバックグラウンドで動かしています。

```
geth --networkid "15" --nodiscover --datadir "/home/ubuntu/eth_private_net" 2>> /home/ubuntu/eth_private_net/geth_err.log &
```

次に下記のコマンドでコンソールを開きます。ここでエラーが出ます。

```
geth --datadir "/home/ubuntu/eth_private_net" attach ipc:/home/ubuntu/eth_data/geth.ipc
```

以下エラー文です。
 `Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /home/mejiro03/eth_data/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory`
下記のサイトの内容を実行しています。
https://book.ethereum-jp.net/first_use/connect_to_private_net.html

Comment: `mejiro03` てどこから出てきたんでしょうか？

Comment: ユーザー名です。コマンドのなかだったらubuntuになってます。

Comment: すみません、ユーザ名なのは分かっていて、つぎのような意味でした：コマンドはどちらも ubuntu ユーザのフォルダしか指定していないのに、エラーメッセージでは mejiro03 の geth.ipc が無いと言っている。どうしてそのパスを attach コマンドは見ようとしているのか、どこかに設定してあるのか？

Comment: もしお使いの Ubuntu のユーザー名が mejiro03 なら、そのドキュメントで `/home/ubuntu` と書いてあるところは全部 `/home/mejiro03` で置き換えて読む必要があると思います。